# Xcode - Hide View Controller Scene Panel

Tags: xcode

I am completely new to Xcode. I would like to hide the View Controller Scene panel, so that I can follow on with a tutorial, and have more screen real estate. I understand that I can hide the left and right panels, but it's the panel I have highlighted in red which I want to hide. Many thanks.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a small icon representing that panel at the bottom of the storyboard view. It's just to the left of the spot that says "View as: iPhone 8..." in your image. Click that icon to toggle the visibility of the storyboard outline view.

There's also a menu command: **Editor->Hide Document Outline** that does the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Press the highlighted icon to hide the side panel.

Answer (score 1):

For xcode 11.3 you may hide the preview by

> Editor->Preview

make sure it is not checked.